# How to restrict keys to ones defined in typescript when keys are accessed through brackets

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to setup a type in typescript so it errors when you try to access a property that isn't defined through this type of access `exampleVar['test string']`.

For example

```
type Account = {
  accountInfo: accountInfo;
  key: number;
}

type accountInfo = {
  'Date Reported'?: string | null;
  'Status': string | null;
}

const testAccount: Account = {
  accountInfo: {},
  key: 1
}

// This gives me a typescript error (which is expected)
testAccount.accountInfo.randomKey;

// This does not give me a typescript error (which is expected)
testAccount.accountInfo.Status;

// This does not give me a typescript error (when I want one)
testAccount.accountInfo['hello test'];
```

Comment: Use `--strict` compiler option.  Or at least `--noImplicitAny`

Comment: No change, also if possible i'd like the solution to just target this specific type definition.

Comment: Are you sure your compiler options are working where you expect them to?  If I use `--noImplicitAny` I get an error, like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAtNSDeAoJukBcBPGZAQXngHsBXYfJAXkxz1YStvwElgAzSgFxJ2NOj34BuFq1wBrCISHBqYAEYQATlNYBfHNILFkIzuMqNmMvAHIAIiHzIAShBiUNjgCbWA-EKj4GgCWwADmSAA+SMoANjHaVkjWAMr4DtRQ1v6BIeFRsfEGegZUwAEE0PjkHHRC1aL0TNiJwhQNZkIYSKnpUErUcUg6ADQGrPKKSACMRVgGjgH1nAB0JmJ8lADa1gAWEHHmC-jWALpSOkA).  Can you provide a [mcve] of your issue?

Comment: Is it possible to work within the file itself to fix the issue? I have 1000s of files and if I change typescript settings themselves i'll have 1000s of typescript errors/warnings to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should use the [`--strict` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#strict) in TypeScript wherever possible.  This is not done by default to support older projects, which is unfortunate, because a lot of the benefits of TypeScript come from these strict checks.  In any case the particular compiler option responsible for this would be [`--noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#noImplicitAny).

The compiler intentionally allows bracket index accesses to bypass the normal property check.  However, if you do such an index and the key does not exist in the property, then the type of the property will be inferred by the compiler to be `any`.  And `--noImplicitAny` will make that a warning, since you are getting an `any` without annotating it:

```
testAccount.accountInfo['hello test'];
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"hello test"' 
// can't be used to index type 'accountInfo'.  Property 'hello test' does not exist 
// on type 'accountInfo'.
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAtNSDeAoJukBcBPGZAQXngHsBXYfJAXkxz1YStvwElgAzSgFxJ2NOj34BuFq1wBrCISHBqYAEYQATlNYBfHNILFkIzuMqNmMvAHIAIiHzIAShBiUNjgCbWA-EKj4GgCWwADmSAA+SMoANjHaVkjWAMr4DtRQ1v6BIeFRsfEGOkhYBlTAAQTQ+OQcdEK1ovRM2InCFE1mQhhIqelQStRxSDoANAas8opIAIxFpayOAY2cAHQmYnyUANrWABYQceZL+NYAugm4APRXAH73D49Pzy8vBjdIAKIxEJB0SEEwDAYkF4EF8DFCEg9iAoMJgEkQMBCNZDCQkOp4CAMsgIAAPGAaaBQIKUBGUXho5DWABEByOVQCNNR7yuSCxwGs9HUSBxngI5hCnnxVMRHVMW2sq1wAAUNJQSB4oftDjFjtVUZ5KNBopR6PigpVWUgyaLrBtuJLVlgdEA)

That's the error you want: "property does not exist on type".

---

Another possibility is to use a linter like ESLINT with a rule like [`dot-notation`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/dot-notation) which disallows using string literals as property indexes at all.

---

I'm afraid that I don't know of any less drastic solution which targets a single object type.  You might be able to configure your linter so that only certain *files* are affected, which may or may not be good enough.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!